# Application insights usage

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there any easy way to find out which applications are using a particular application insights from azure portal?

I have checked the various options in the portals but don't find any easy to understand interface where I can find the list of applications which are sending data to that particular application insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application map is good. You can also go to Performance, then choose Roles. Roles is in the same tab group as Operations and Dependencies. This will give you a listing of all services that use that Application Insights instance. This has the added benefit of allowing you to expand a particular node and see the actual instances.

This same approach also works for the Failures tab. You can see the number of calls and failures rolled up per service, and also see the breakout metrics per instance.

Answer (score 2):

The application map should provide you with a good view of various resources using the app insights resource